# Why am I getting enter parameter value in my sql code

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT Forename, test1, test2, test3, test4,  ((test1+test2+test3+test4)/4) AS aMark
FROM Question1
GROUP BY Forename, test1, test2, test3, test4
ORDER BY aMark ASC;
```

I am trying to calculate the average of 4 test marks, but when I execute my code it comes up with a message saying to enter parameter value for 'aMark', would anyone be able to explain why and how I would fix this?

Comment: Which DBMS and tool you are using, Please tag it.

Comment: I am using Access Database 2007-2013

Comment: Change last line to `ORDER BY 6 ASC`.

Comment: I'm not sure how that makes it work but it does, thank you very much

Comment: @DylanJack `ORDER BY 6 ASC` means sort by column 6 ascending.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll keep that in mind for future sql programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use below query

```
SELECT Question1.*, ((test1+test2+test3+test4)/4) AS aMark
  FROM Question1
ORDER BY ((test1+test2+test3+test4)/4) ASC;
```

[image]

Comment: You should explain why `ORDER BY aMark` does not work.